# Can I run Google's Native Client outside of the browser?

Tags: google-nativeclient

Is it possible to run Google NaCl outside of the browser as a process sandbox?

Comment: I recently asked the same question on the discussion group.  The answer is yes, using sel_ldr, as Mark Seaborn replied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Native Client [documentation](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient) is probably a good starting point for trying to figure out how everything works.

As Mark Seaborn and Bennet Yee indicate, you are probably best off looking into using [sel_ldr](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/design-documents/native-client-integration-with-chrome). More details about how sel_ldr is included in "[The life of sel_ldr](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/life-of-sel_ldr)".

I haven't personally implemented anything that uses NaCl outside of a browser, so I can't unfortunately comment on the ease of doing so.

Comment: Most of the links provided here are expired. I'm interested in running native sandboxed code outside a browser and NaCl may be a perfect solution for that (or not ?).

Comment: @deadalnix I have updated my answer to point to current documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  The standalone build of Native Client contains a program called "sel_ldr" which runs the NaCl sandbox outside of the web browser.  A lot of NaCl's test suite tests NaCl by running programs under sel_ldr rather than under the browser.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Mark's answer, take a look at the sel_universal target.  There are obviously some interfaces that cannot be supported, e.g., Pepper interfaces, since such a stand-alone run doesn't involve a browser.  Furthermore, the stable ABI that we support is that which is exposed by the "integrated runtime" or irt, and the irt code thunk assumes that the browser is present.  a standalone use of NaCl via sel_ldr would probably have to use the syscall interface initially, until an alternate irt is written.  (NB: we make no guarantees about the stability of the syscall interface.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `run.py` which included in Native Client's source.

Here is an example that runs a hello world program.

```
make test_hello_world_nexe
python native_client/run.py out/Debug/hello_world_newlib_x64.nexe
```

This script can build, search and invoke `sel_ldr`, and pass proper arguments to it automatically.